# Stop http request after certain condition using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have my HTTP request and have some conditions need to wait get at least 1 results or complete=true from the response.

I also want to add if keep executing to satisfy the below condition I want to stop after some request, my code:

```
if (vars.get('complete') == true || vars.get('total_result') > 0) {
    vars.put('stop', true);
}
```

[image]

My request:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a String when getting vars value and failed to compare to 0.

You can parse value as Integer:

```
int total_result = vars.get('total_result') == null ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(vars.get('total_result'))
if (vars.get('complete') == true || total_result > 0) {
    vars.put('stop', true);
}
```

Comment: HI,my script is working fine to compare >0,my question here some time my API won't give response(it always total result= 0 and complete==false) so this case script always looking for condition instead i need to stop the particular thread after some number of requests

Comment: @SinuReddy You can add a counter and check counter value in script

Answer (score 0):

You have a significant number of errors in the [jmeter.log file:](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

[image]

so first of all you need to analyze what's going on there, it might be the case the variables are not having respective values.

Also [since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) you're supposed to be using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for scripting so consider migrating from JavaScript, moreover it is [not available in later Java](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372) versions

Also JMeter Variables are stored as [Java Strings](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_strings.asp) so you need to perform the strings comparison or conversion of values to the required types

Suggested clause change (again assumes Groovy language):

```
vars.get('complete') == 'true' || (vars.get('total_result') as int) > 0
```